# Angular Routing - AuthenticationGuard for Child Modules not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing

In my application I have created multiple nested modules and routes.

In the routing module AuthenticationGuard (canActivate property) is set only for the '/parent' route. And AuthenticationGuard is **not** configured explicitly for any of the child modules.

The routing modules looks similar to this;

app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'parent', canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard], loadChildren: () => import('./parent').then(m => m.ParentModule) }
```

child-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'child', loadChildren: () => import('./child').then(m => m.ChildModule) }
```

grandchild-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: '', component: GrandChildComponent }
```

According to the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#properties) "By default, any user can activate a child." unless we provide a route guard to the canActivateChild property;

[image]

But in my case, if I directly hit the urls of any child modules (ie. /parent/child, /parent/child/grandchild), the AuthenticationGuard of parent module is getting invoked, and the child module is loaded only if it returns true.

As per the official documentation the parent's AuthenticationGuard shouldn't get invoked, and access to child URLs should be enabled by default.

Can someone explain this? Is there an error in the documentation, or did I get this wrong altogether ?

Comment: @RaviGajera that's incorrect in pretty much every way.

Comment: You need to use `canLoad` as opposed to `canActivate` (you'll need a different guard) when authenticating lazily loaded child routes